# Does private variables have the same access as package/default/no modifier variables in private classes?

Tags: java, variables, private

Does private variables have the same access as package/default/no modifier variables in private classes?

```
public class PublicClass {

    public void test() {

        InnerClass in = new InnerClass();

        in.name1 = "a";
        in.name2 = "b";

        in.getName1();
        in.getName2();

    }

    private class InnerClass {

        private String name1;
        String name2;

        private String getName1() {
            return name1;
        }

        String getName2() {
            return name2;
        }

    }

}
```

The method test has access to both name1 and name2, so, what is the purpose of setting private on variables in private classes?

Update: A code example how the private keyword actually disallows access would be great.

Comment: Variables don't access each other. Methods access *fields* and it doesn't matter which variable or field you used to access a field or method of another class.

Comment: The variable access modifier for inner classes takes effect mainly when the inner class is public/package private, otherwise, it wont matter

Comment: Hm, when did i say variables access each other?

Answer (score 1):

Private members are accessible anywhere within the top-level enclosing class, i.e. `PublicClass` as defined in the [JLS 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

So there is no way to prevent a method from accessing the private members of inner classes.

As your inner class is private, you can declare its members the way you want (including public), they will only be accessible within `OuterClass`.

Answer (score 0):

`private` means/allows access inside the same (top level) class. You are using an inner class...

From the Java language specification:

> A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1

So not much use in declaring methods/fields private in inner private classes in this case indeed.
If you move the `InnerClass`outside the body of the `PublicClass` (can have it in the same file still, though can't declare the classs private then) you will see the difference.